# Problem with inserting into a tableview with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, sigabrt

I'm new to Swift and I have to present some data in a tableView, I got the code from the internet but it does not work and I get the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" notification but I have no unused / disconnected outlets.

I already looked for solutions but didn't find any suitable for me and I don't know anybody who programs in swift.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Table: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func click(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var temp: String = text.text ?? "test"
    var arr: [String]  = []
    arr.append(temp)

    Table.beginUpdates()
    Table.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: arr.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    Table.endUpdates()

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're in the right place and you'll find help here; I fixed a couple of typos in your question, but can't answer. Only consider that SIGABRT does not mean that you have a disconnected outlet. I let other users help you find the actual cause, my impression is that you're missing some code from the tutorial you're starting with (UITableView delegate and datasource methods, specifically).

Comment: The best way forward is probably to find an online tutorial about UITableView (there should be plenty available) because I get the feeling it’s way to much missing in your code to make this question meaningful.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I already tried 2 different tutorials about UITableViews but every time I get the same Error as explains above. Sure I am missing something every time which is kind of embarrassing but I am running against solid walls with this problem and would be glad for any type of help.

Comment: The problem is that with that little code your question is too broad and impossible to answer in a concise way. As mentioned in the first comment, have you implemented the datasource and delegate methods?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am sorry, this is just a sample project as I am not allowed to show the actual code from the project. I already tried it before with tableview.delegate = self and tableview.dataSource = self but it didn't work, now I tried it again, exactly the same code in the same project and now it is working